# How can I get an arranged array from a post when no sending values?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, mongoose

I'm trying to create a formulary where someone can edit values. The thing, is I want to send everything with a submit.
[image]

Now when I console.log(req.body), all the data I get from the submit.
It sends me the values not ordered, I mean, in the image above I wrote "111" in my 4 input to get the value in my array on position 4...But I get it like this:

```
  Unidad: [
    '111', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',
    ... 420 more items
```

While I would like to get it like this so I can manipulate that specific value with its index.

```
  Unidad: [
    '', '', '', '', '111', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '',
    ... 420 more items
```

This is my form of how I submit the values

```
<form action="/EdicionMaterialesPost" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<% for (var a = 0; a < materiales.length; a++) { %>

<tr> 

    <th> <%=materiales[a].Descripcion%> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion"> 
    </th>                                
    <th>    <%=materiales[a].Codigo%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Codigo" name="Codigo"> 
                                        
    </th>
    <th>  <%=materiales[a].Unidad%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Unidad" name="Unidad" >
                                        
    </th>
    <th>  <%=materiales[a].PrecioUnitario%> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="PrecioUnitario" name="PrecioUnitario">

    </th>
    <th>   <%=materiales[a].Familia%> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Familia" name="Familia">
                                        
    </th>
    <th>   <%=materiales[a].SubFam%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="SubFam" name="SubFam">
                                        
    </th>

</tr>      
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="DescripcionBusqueda" name="DescripcionBusqueda" value="<%=materiales[a].Descripcion%>">

<% } %>
<button type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Guardar Cambios</button></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had a weird solution. While rage typing I saw that if I sent first a value, the array is sent ordered with the inputs.
So I put hidden input and began my for starting with value 1 to skip the hidden values.

```
<form action="/EdicionMaterialesPost" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion" value="tamales"> 
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  id="Codigo" name="Codigo"value="tamales"> 
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  id="Unidad" name="Unidad"value="tamales" >
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="PrecioUnitario" name="PrecioUnitario"value="312913289">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Familia" name="Familia"value="tamales">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  id="SubFam" name="SubFam"value="tamales">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="DescripcionBusqueda" name="DescripcionBusqueda" value="tamales">


<% for (var a = 0; a < materiales.length; a++) { %>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="DescripcionBusqueda" name="DescripcionBusqueda" value="<%=materiales[a].Descripcion%>">

<tr> 

    <th> <%=materiales[a].Descripcion%> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion"> 
    </th>                                
    <th>    <%=materiales[a].Codigo%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Codigo" name="Codigo"> 
                                        
    </th>
    <th>  <%=materiales[a].Unidad%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Unidad" name="Unidad" >
                                        
    </th>
    <th>  <%=materiales[a].PrecioUnitario%> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="PrecioUnitario" name="PrecioUnitario">

    </th>
    <th>   <%=materiales[a].Familia%> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Familia" name="Familia">
                                        
    </th>
    <th>   <%=materiales[a].SubFam%> <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="SubFam" name="SubFam">
                                        
    </th>

</tr>      

<% } %>
<button type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Guardar Cambios</button></form>
```